# Deploying to separate accounts with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two aws accounts : production and staging.  I'm using aws-cli v3 to deploy via GIT to my production environment using `eb deploy`

I want to be able to deploy to my staging environment regularly from my **develop** branch and when it comes to deploying a release I want to be able to deploy from my newly created **release** branch to my production environment.

I already have my ~/.aws/config file with my two account key sets (staging and production), and would like to be able to do something like:

```
eb deploy --profile staging
```

and

```
eb deploy --profile production
```

Is it necessary to have the two environments under the same account and use `eb use production-env` and `eb use staging-env`?

Comment: did you found answer for this question ? I have same problem, if you have answer please answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: I just cloned my GIT repo down as another local copy as `my_app_staging`.  That way I could use `eb init` to have a separate aws config (stored locally) using the keys for my staging account.  Any time I want to deploy to staging I cd to this directory and pull the remote repo and `eb deploy` from there.

Comment: is not solution to deploy to ~10 app ...

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147180/aws-elastic-beanstalk-deploy-to-multiple-applications#37154225)

Also it does look like the eb command does support profiles

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html#eb3-cmd-options